# Integrate Credit Card Debit Card NetBanking Airtel Money in wordpress and asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, payment-gateway

I want to know how to integrate indian payment options in wordpress website and asp.net website

I want to integrate following to my website

- Credit Card
- Debit Card
- NetBanking
- Airtel Money

How can i more details on this? Is there any plugins that support all these features??

Comment: I'm also looking for such a plugin. Most of the plugins support PayPal and other american options only. Needs a plugin that support Net-banking option. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is any direct plugin to support online money transactions. The payment gateways in India are paid services and you have to contact some authority like billdesk etc.

Comment: I want to know step-by-step process to implement it with php / asp.net

Comment: Since the payment gateways are paid service the respective service providers can provide you the full instructions.